# How can I use variables in open(COMMAND, $command) function?

Tags: perl, variables, aix

First time asking a question here, so I hope I get the formatting right:

```
my %config;
$config{variable1}=epaMQMonitor;
$config{variable2}=IntroscopeEPAgent;

#issue the ps grep
my $command = 'ps -ef |grep -w $config{variable1} |grep -wi $config{variable2} |grep -v grep > /wilyagent/BriansPerlTesting/applytest.txt|';
print "Command is ps -ef |grep -w $config{variable1} |grep -wi $config{variable2} |grep -v grep > /wilyagent/BriansPerlTesting/applytest.txt|\n";
print "$command\n";
open( COMMAND, $command )
|| die "Error when executing \"$command\": $!";
```

Now, my expected output for both would be:

```
Command is ps -ef |grep -w epaMQMonitor |grep -wi IntroscopeEPAgent |grep -v grep > /wilyagent/BriansPerlTesting/applytest.txt|
```

Instead, I'm getting this for the second one (and this appears to be what is being run):

```
ps -ef |grep -w $config{variable1} |grep -wi $config{variable2} |grep -v grep > /wilyagent/BriansPerlTesting/applytest.txt|
```

Further digging has revealed that Perl is substituting the first level variable ($command) for its contents, but it is not pulling the $config{variable1} and $config{variable2} into it (I think because it considers the $command as a package?)

I found a way to get the output I want:

```
open my $command, "ps -ef |grep -w $config{variable1} |grep -wi $config{variable2} |grep -v grep > /wilyagent/BriansPerlTesting/applytest.txt|";
close($command);
```

However, that doesn't work with an "or die" function on the end.

My question, ultimately; is it possible to get the variable substitution working in the first method, and if so, how?

Background - the reason for this is we have a series of perl scripts currently that are hard-coded. It has been requested that we make these scripts portable to other servers without having to edit the scripts themselves, having them look at a configuration file that lists what they are looking for (in this case, it is a script that looks for processes that should be running on a server).

Thanks!

Comment: In `$config{variable1}=epaMQMonitor;`, is `epaMQMonitor` supposed to be a string, or is it a function? If it's a string, you have a syntax error. You should `use strict` and `use warnings`. That would tell you what is wrong. You need to quote all your strings.

Comment: There's also a difference between `or die` and `|| die`. The logical operators have a different _stickiness_. In general, the `||` type binary operators have way higher _precedence_ than the `or` type logical operators. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html for more information.

Comment: After you solve the interpolation problem bear in mind that since you are passing `$config{variable1}` and `$config{variable2}` through to the shell, you must completely trust the source of what those variables contain. Otherwise you will eventually have a very bad day.  Who controls the configuration files?

Comment: Many thanks for the info - I'm a perl newbie still (a lot of this is existing script that I'm modifying for the config file). Regarding control of the config files - they will be setup by our team (nobody external). the epaMQMonitor is a string (it is just text that we are looking to match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
my $command = 'ps -ef |grep -w $config{variable1} |grep -wi $config{variable2} |grep -v grep > /wilyagent/BriansPerlTesting/applytest.txt|';
```

you set up the variable `$command`. And since you use single quotes `'...'` the variables will not be substituted. Use double quotes `"..."` instead for variable substitution to take place.